# Who composed the English hornpipe, "The Rake"?

Tags: unknown-composer

"The Rake" is an English hornpipe.  I saw an online a citation of this including the composer name and the year, but I now cannot find it and I have forgotten the name of the composer.

Comment: Leaving aside the authorship, is this the right song? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBh3Q2ylQ2w

Comment: @Aaron I'm not at all sure, but I don't that would be a hornpipe. [Looks like](https://www.reddit.com/r/spongebob/comments/nil6zs/origin_of_the_rake_hornpipe_the_iconic_krusty/) "The Rake Hornpipe" is famous as background music in the Krusty Krab restaurant in Spongebob Squarepants, and is an original composition by Robert Alexander White dating from 1985.

Comment: [The Session](https://thesession.org/tunes/15041) has notation for it, some versions about as confused as the assertion that it's "a 16th century traditional hornpipe composed by Robert Alexander White."

Answer (score 2):

The [tune](https://thesession.org/tunes/15041) was written in 1985 by Robert White and used as background music in the "Krusty Krab" restaurant in "Spongebob Squarepants".

From a discussion at [Reddit](https://thesession.org/tunes/15041):

> I managed to get in contact with Robert White, the man who wrote the song. He told me that he wrote The Rake Hornpipe in about 1985. It was originally written for a video for a training college, but it never ended up being used. Later in the future when he was recording music for the Folk Songs - Story Songs - Part 2 album for KPM, he included The Rake Hornpipe in the album.